# Angular 4 Jhipster jhiSortBy sorting does not work on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jhipster

I have following problem on angular 4 (using JHipster) on IE11 and older versions of Firefox (v42).

```html
<th jhiSortBy="fieldName"><span>fieldName</span><span class="fa fa-sort"></span></th>
```

After either prod/dev build, browsers like IE 11 or Firefox (v42) make no action on that part of code. Newest browsers have no problems with that.

TSconfig.js:

```js
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
        "outDir": "target/www/app",
        "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types"
        ]
    },
    "include": [
        "src/main/webapp/app",
        "src/test/javascript"
    ]
}
```

Error I am getting in console is like this:

```js
ERROR TypeError: this.element.querySelectorAll(...).forEach is not a function
stack:
vendor</o</t.prototype.resetClasses@http://localserver:8980/app/vendor.dll.js:793:3800
vendor</o</t.prototype.sort@http://localserver:8980/app/vendor.dll.js:793:3560
vendor</s</t.prototype.onClick@http://localserver:8980/app/vendor.dll.js:904:15335
View_t_3/<@ng:///e/t.ngfactory.js:275:21
Rn/_@http://localserver:8980/app/vendor.dll.js:120:1448
Or@http://localserver:8980/app/vendor.dll.js:120:11163
dr@http://localserver:8980/app/vendor.dll.js:120:9142
$t@http://localserver:8980/app/vendor.dll.js:71:1650
Ee/<@http://localserver:8980/app/vendor.dll.js:78:2419
m/<@http://localserver:8980/app/vendor.dll.js:506:775
[284]/</</w</_</e.prototype.invokeTask@http://localserver:8980/app/52da49a0e142d3943281.polyfills.bundle.js:43:10600
vendor</</qo</t.prototype.forkInnerZoneWithAngularBehavior/this.inner<.onInvokeTask@http://localserver:8980/app/vendor.dll.js:176:8016
[284]/</</w</_</e.prototype.invokeTask@http://localserver:8980/app/52da49a0e142d3943281.polyfills.bundle.js:43:10513
[284]/</</w</g</t.prototype.runTask@http://localserver:8980/app/52da49a0e142d3943281.polyfills.bundle.js:43:5489
e/this.invoke@http://localserver:8980/app/52da49a0e142d3943281.polyfills.bundle.js:43:11561
 t.ngfactory.js:264:8

ERROR CONTEXT Object { view: Object, nodeIndex: 9, nodeDef: Object, elDef: Object, elView: Object } t.ngfactory.js:264:8
```

Comment: Open the browser console. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: You may need to use polyfills. See https://angular.io/guide/browser-support.

Comment: I forgot to add console logs. I just added them :)

Comment: I am adding shim.min.js in cases when userAgent is IE or Firefox 4x.

Comment: Looks strange. IE 11 supports forEach and querySelectorAll out-of-the-box. See https://caniuse.com/#search=forEach and https://caniuse.com/#search=querySelectorAll. If no elements found, querySelectorAll returns an empty array. So, forEach should be accessible on it. Can you provide with a runnable project to illustrate the issue? For example, in Plunker.